# Jquery Prepend animation only works once with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ok so I have an AJAX long poll running and each time the database is updated I have jquery add the info received from ajax into a div.

Jquery will add the information everytime the database is updated but it will only do the animation the first time. I've tried a lot of different things and have gotten a lot of different and some weird results. I am new to Jquery so if you could elaborate on your explaination that would be greatly appreciated.

here is my AJAX function.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'feedupdate.php',
        data: {function: '3test', datacheck: var_numcheck, javaid: var_IDcheck},
        success: function (check) {
            console.log(check);
            var verify = JSON.parse(check);

            if (var_IDcheck < verify['id']) {
                var_IDcheck = verify['id'];
                for (var i=0;i<var_IDcheck;i++){
                  $('#datacheck').prepend(verify[i]).slideDown('slow');




          }
          }
          setTimeout('activitycheck()',5000);
          },
    error: function(check) {
    console.log(check);
    setTimeout('activitycheck()',5000);
      }
      });
    } 


  $(document).ready(function()  {
   activitycheck();
  }); // document ready
```

Comment: Get rid of the `setTimeout('activitycheck()',5000);` in the two places you have them. And put it in the document.ready, in place of just `activitycheck()`.

Comment: Also the I strongly disadvise the use of just `setTimeout('activitycheck()',5000);` . Change it to: `setTimeout(function(){activitycheck()},5000);` Or just to: `setTimeout(activitycheck,5000);` when you dont need any parameters in the activitycheck.

Comment: when i just put setTimeout('activitycheck()',5000); it only will post once instead of every five seconds.

Comment: yeah the whole long poll stops working if i take out the setimeout

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that `setTimeout('activitycheck()',5000);` is the write choice use

```
setInterval('activitycheck()',5000);
```

it helped me a lot.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-setinterval-function

Comment: you don't have to call the set interval 2 time you can easily write it out side the function it will directly it will call all the time .you can write it above </script> tag